# Const in auto type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, auto, effective-c++

I am reading Effective modern C++ from Scott Meyers. Item 1 contains the following example:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& param);       // param is a reference
int x = 27;             // x is an int
const int cx = x;       // cx is a const int
f(cx);                  // T is const int,
                        // param's type is const int&
```

In Item 3 appears the following example:

```
Widget w;
const Widget& cw = w;
auto myWidget1 = cw;             // auto type deduction:
                                 // myWidget1's type is Widget
```

Based on Item 1 I expected `myWidget1`'s type to be `const Widget`. Am I missing something?

Comment: `auto&` is the equivalent for `T&`

Comment: @Piotr Skotnick:  Thank you!

Comment: On what I call a "right expression", on the right of `=` (ordinary assignment, copy initialization) and with by-value parameter passing, const doesn't matter; on the right of the `=` of ref binding, const does matter.

Comment: Try using `T param` (i.e without reference), then you'll see the similarity with `auto myWidget1`... Or use `auto & myWidget1` to be same as `T & param`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction:

§ 7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]/p6:

> Once the type of a *declarator-id* has been determined according to 8.3, the type of the declared variable
>   using the *declarator-id* is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for template argument
>   deduction. Let `T` be the type that has been determined for a variable identifier `d`. Obtain `P` from `T` by
>   replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter `U` or, if the initializer
>   is a *braced-init-list* (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`. The type deduced for the variable `d` is then the deduced `A` determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1).

§ 14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call]/p2:

> If `P` is not a reference type:
>
> - [...]
> - If `A` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `A`'s type **are ignored for type deduction**.

If you want `myWidget1` to be of type `const Widget&`, it should be declared as a reference type, e.g.:

```
auto& myWidget1 = cw;
//  ^
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/558ac8beddc01abd)

Comment: 'should' is the wrong keyword here, you 'can' declare it as`auto&`. You can also specify the `const`keyword, it would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

`auto myWidget1 = cw;` follows the third rule of template argument type deduction in Meyers book, which is pass by value. 
When you pass by value, cv-qualifiers and references are ignored, because you are getting a new copy of the object, so you don't really care if the old object that you copied from was const or a reference.