# type deduction c++ standard and auto

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

If i understood correctly, we have 3 cases in type deduction:

1) param is not reference nor pointer.

```
   int x = 5;
   template< typename T>
   func( T param ) 

   template< typename T>
   func1( T & param ) 

   func(x)
   func1(x)
```

in both cases T is deduced to be `int`

2) param is pointer or reference , in this case we ignore reference and pointer -ness

```
   template< typename T>
   func( T & param ) 

   int x = 5;
   const int y =x;
   const int &z =x;

   func(x) // param is type int & and T is type int 
   func(y) // param is type const int & and T is type const int
   func(z) // param is type const int & and T is type const int
```

3) param is "universal reference".

```
template< typename T>
func( T && param )

int x = 5;
const int y = x;
const int & z = x;
func(x) // param is type int & and T is type int &
func(y) // param is type const int & T is type const int &
func(z) // param is type const int & and T is type const int &
func(5) // param is type int && and T is type int &&
```

The `auto` keyword decides type like template deduction with the exception of

`auto x = {1 , 2 , 3}` where type of `auto x` is `initalizer_list`

However how does this work with constness? 
Having

```
struct Test{ int x };
Test t;
const Test & t1 = t;
auto t2 = t1; // t2 is type of Test not const Test &
```

For example if we passed

const int* const x = ...

In what cases would be constness ignored and what consntess would prevail?

Comment: `func(5) // param is type int && and T is type int &&` - wrong. `param` is `int&&` while `T` is `int`.

Comment: @yeputons: Incorrect, pointers can have [_qualification conversions_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions). That is a special case. And since this question explicitly mentions const-ness, those qualification conversions should be part of the answer.

Comment: you don't make much sense to me: your 3 types of deduction seem... confusing... 1st case: you say it's not a reference then you show a reference in the example. 2nd you say pointer and you show no pointer example and you say "we ignore pointer-ness" and I can't think of an interpretation of that statement that could be true.

Comment: try this: edit your answer by using the right terminology: parameter is when you declare/define a function, argument is what you provide to a function when you call it. For instance: `void foo(int a) ;`  `foo(b)` here `a` is parameter, `b` is argument. And revisit that "pointer" shenanigan. I can't see a scenario when the pointer type is ignored in a deducing context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Const in auto type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872991/const-in-auto-type-deduction)

Answer (score 0):

`auto` uses the same rules as [`template argument deduction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> Once the type of the initializer has been determined, the compiler determines the type that will replace the keyword `auto` using the rules for template argument deduction from a function call

So, following your example:

```
struct Test{ int x };
Test t;
const Test & t1 = t;
auto t2 = t1; // t2 is Test
const auto t3 = t1; // t3 is const Test
```